# Absolute continuity of two-dimensional measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Absolute continuity has two different meanings: one for functions and one for measures. The Wikipedia page [explains the relation between the two notions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity) in the following way:

> A finite measure μ on Borel subsets of the real line is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure if and only if the point function:
>   $$F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$$
>   is locally an absolutely continuous real function. In other words, a function is locally absolutely continuous if and only if its derivative is a measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Does this relation have a parallel in two dimensions?

I.e., if a measure μ on Borel subsets of $R^2$ is absolutely continuous (with respect to area), is there a related 2-dimensional function $F_μ(x,y)$ which is guaranteed to be continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure.  Consider $F_\mu(x,y) = \mu\left((-\infty,x] \times (-\infty,y]\right)$.  Then 
$$\mu((a,b] \times (c,d]) = F_\mu(b,d) - F_\mu(a,d) - F_\mu(b,c) + F_\mu(a,c)$$
The right generalization of absolute continuity to this setting would seem to be
that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for any $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$, $i=1\ldots n$, with
$a_i \le b_i$, $c_i \le d_i$, $\sum_i (d_i - c_i)(b_i - a_i) < \delta$, 
we have $$ \sum_i \left|F(b_i,d_i) - F(a_i,d_i) - F(b_i,c_i) + F(a_i,c_i)\right| < \epsilon$$

Comment: How would you show that $F$ is continuous?

Comment: Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N$ such that $|\mu|(\mathbb R \cap (-\infty, -N]) < \epsilon/4$, so $|F_\mu(x,-N)| < \epsilon/4$ for all $x$.  Then $|F_\mu(x,y) - F_\mu(x',y)| < \epsilon$ if $|F_\mu(x,y) - F_\mu(x',y) - F_\mu(x,-N) + F_\mu(x',-N)| < \epsilon/2$.  Similarly for $|F_\mu(x',y) - F_\mu(x',y')|$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get why we have $|F_{\mu}(x,y)-F_{\mu}(x',y)-F_{\mu}(x,-N)+F_{\mu}(x',-N)| < \epsilon/2 \ $. If you use absolute continuity, couldn't it happen that $|(x-x')(y+N)| > \delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$?